# Flutter - how to vertically align text input within a container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to add a search input control to the app header in my Flutter web app.

See...

```
Widget _buildSearchControl() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: 300,
      child: TextField(
        style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.white, color: Colors.black),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.black,),
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear,color: Colors.black,),
              onPressed: () {
                /* Clear the search field */
              },
            ),
            hintText: 'Search...',
            border: InputBorder.none),
      ),
    );
  }
```

However, when entering the text, the characters are not vertically centre aligned as I wpuld expect

[image]

Is there a way I can have the characters input to the TextField control vertically centered so that they line up with the icons?

Comment: Working fine here. Looks like device specific issue. On what device are you testing?

Comment: try to use `isDense: true,` inside `decoration: InputDecoration(`

Answer (score 0):

Use this , maybe it depends on your contentPadding

```
Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 56,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
      child: TextFormField(
        key: widget.globalKey,
        autocorrect: false,
        onTap: widget.onClick,
        minLines: widget.minLines,
        maxLines: widget.maxLines,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        onChanged: (val) => widget.onChangeValue(val),
        style: getInputStyle,
        initialValue: widget.initialValue,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        controller: widget.controller,
        keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: REdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
              14, 16, 0, 16),
          labelText: widget.labelText,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
          labelStyle: getLabelStyle,
          hintStyle: getLabelStyle,
          fillColor: widget.backGroundColor ,
          filled: true,
          prefix: widget.prefix, 
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this textAlignVertical property?

```
TextField(
 textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
 ....
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrap the *Container* with *Padding*.

And add `contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),` to *InputDecoration*

```
...
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0).copyWith(bottom: 0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 2),
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      color: Colors.white
    ),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      onChanged: (string) {},
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        labelText: 'Enter',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.document_scanner_sharp,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child: IconButton(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.clear,
              size: 25,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            tooltip: 'Clear',
            onPressed: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              _controller.clear();
            }
          ),
        )
      )
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]